# Outlier Detection giving almost all training points as outliers

Tags: outliers, one-class, isolation-forest

I am trying to run an outlier detection algorithm using python and I have used OneClassSVM and Isolation Forest on a dataset of about 30 points with 5 outliers. I have trained on the 25 points and using it for remaining 5 points but I am getting almost all training points as outliers and also all the 5 points are outliers as well, of course.

Can someone help me debug what might be going wrong?

Comment: Use more data if possible. Other than that you will have to provide more information (description/plots of data).

Comment: What do you consider an outlier to be for your problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly using the 'contamination' parameter of IsolationForest?

Comment: No. Could you point me as where should I read about it?